# typescript - return an object with key equals to an input string literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to implement the following 'createCounter' function?

```
function createCounter(key: string) {
    return {[key]:0} // Note this doesn't work
}

const obj = createCounter('sum')
obj.sum += 20 // works
obj.prop = 0  // oops: no such property
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via specifying a generic for the `key` parameter.  Here's your code with the correct behavior:

```
function createCounter<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K): { [H in K]: Record<H, number> }[K] {
    return { [key]: 0 } as any; // a cast is sadly required because TS isn't smart enough
}

const obj = createCounter('sum')
obj.sum += 20 // works
obj.prop = 0  // oops: no such property
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQYTubFAHgGlE0APbMAEwGdEAFFOABzRSgE8S0uA+ABQBrPgC5EJAJQSA3ogDaACUQwkJALoSASmghwUNIkoA0iMCAC2AIw79EAXwWbEsgLAAoRN8TooIFCR5BVEuLUQABkdEDAYMMC4AbkQAehSY5FioVQY6DBoAGy5fNABHEBh0GkRbCAwQOjREABUAZRywAHJsuksMTnIwfABzAAtPB09PfTA6bLhrACtEAF5kdCxcfDBCQU66K06pTwXFgDoDy0QAajWAJii0xAB3A2E6E6Wz1hZWVcjvE84Gw6BIhogDhBRogfmwONxPEA)

Comment: Beware that if `K` is a union then weird things happen; `createCounter(Math.random()<0.5 ? "foo" : "bar")` *should* produce a `{foo: number} | {bar: number}` but your version will return `{foo: number, bar: number}`.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, didn't catch that. I've handled that case now thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's *very* important to handle that case, but it's one of the many things mentioned in [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), the bug report about TS not being smart enough to do the right thing with computed property keys.